# Sending array data from one view controller to another

Tags: swift

I am trying to copy an array from one view controller to another view controller, but somehow it does not work.. I have tried using this code:

```
let otherVC = TerningspilletViewController()
        mineSpillere = otherVC.mineSpillere2
        println("otherVC")
```

In the view controller i want to send the data from has this code:

```
var mineSpillere = ["Spiller 1", "Spiller 2", "Spiller 3"]
```

The view controller that is going to received this data, has this code:

```
var mineSpillere2 = [String]()
```

the "`var mineSpillere`" is going to show the text, but when i try to show it, it says that the "`var mineSpillere`" is empty. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Maybe you shold reverse the `mineSpillere = otherVC.mineSpillere2` to `otherVC.mineSpillere2` if you want to assign to mineSpillere2?

Comment: @Laffen - I have done that, but still does not work..

Comment: Where is the line `var mineSpillere2 = [String]()` make sure it's outside of the  methods and maybe think about using a  `!` or `?`

Comment: Your example tells me that  `var mineSpillere` is assigned the value of `otherVC.mineSpillere2` which doesn't hold any data.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access array of another viewController then you can save it in memory and for that you can use `NSUserDefaults` this way:

```
//save
var mineSpillere = ["Spiller 1", "Spiller 2", "Spiller 3"]
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(mineSpillere, forKey: "YourKey")
```

Now you can read it from anywhere this way:

```
//read
if let testArray : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourKey") {
    var readArray : [NSString] = testArray! as! [NSString]
    println(readArray)
}
```

And if you want to do with your old way here is code:

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var mineSpillere = ["Spiller 1", "Spiller 2", "Spiller 3"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var mineSpillere2 = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let otherVC = FirstViewController()
        mineSpillere2 = otherVC.mineSpillere
        println(mineSpillere2)  //[Spiller 1, Spiller 2, Spiller 3]
    }

}
```

Comment: I will have to use the first codes you gave me, using NSUserDefaults, but i get error when trying to load: http://s28.postimg.org/iwxu0tf4t/Screen_Shot_2015_07_23_at_15_15_19.png

Comment: check your key. It should be same as you are saving your array.

Comment: Question about the "readArray". How can i put data from "readArray" to "mineSpillere" at viewDidView.

Answer (score 0):

> first checkout are you using story board
>
> if you are using storyboard

```
let otherVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardIdendifier") as? TerningspilletViewController
otherVC.mineSpillere2 =  mineSpillere 
println(otherVc)
```

> otherwise do like this

```
let otherVC = TerningspilletViewController()
    otherVC.mineSpillere2 =  mineSpillere
    println("otherVC")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboards, I suggest passing the data in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TerningspilletViewSegue" {
        let otherVc = segue.destinationViewController as! TerningspilletViewController
        otherVc.mineSpillere = mineSpillere
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code working fine sending data from one viewController to another viewcontroller.just reference of storyboard id you can send data from one view to another view .Then we create that class object based on that object reference we can access that array and those class properties then just append it.

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let secondView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableView") as! TableViewController.
self.present(secondView, animated: true) {
    let data = nameArray
    secondView.models.append(data!)
    secondView.tableView.reloadData()
}
```